# Custom colorscales reverting to default in Plotly (Python)

Tags: python, colors, data-visualization, plotly

I am having trouble getting a custom colorscale to display in Plotly in a choropleth plot of US states. The `z` value represents here a value for each state divided by the mean over all states. An image is linked below.

Specifically, I want the colorscale to `span` the full range of `z`, but have the perceptive midpoint (yellow on a RdBu scale) always sit at 1 (the mean of the data). I would like to capture all the dynamic range while keeping denser color information in the more populous (e.g. around 1) set of states.

My code looks like the following (Try to ignore the contextual bits):

```
def plot_states(sms_range, var='normalized Basic vs DOT', norm=False, timeupper = '2018-10-24',
            timelower = '2010-01-01',
            title = 'Test Figure (Hover for breakdown)'):

df = sms_range[sms_range.index.get_level_values(1) <=
               pd.to_datetime(timeupper)].sort_index()
df = df[df.index.get_level_values(1) >= pd.to_datetime(timelower)].sort_index()


dfmean = df.mean(level=0)

if norm:
    totalmean = df.median()
    plot_z = dfmean[var]/(totalmean[var])
else:
    plot_z = dfmean[var].astype(float)

dfmean['code'] = stateabbreviations[:,1]

minimum = plot_z.min()
maximum = plot_z.max()
onepointlow = ((1. - minimum) / (maximum - minimum))*0.9
onepointhigh = ((1. - minimum) / (maximum - minimum))*1.1

colorscale = [[0.0, 'rgb(49,54,149)'], # Blue
              [onepointlow/2., 'rgb(116,173,209)'],
              [onepointlow, 'rgb(224,243,248)'], # Yellow
              [onepointhigh, 'rgb(254,224,144)'], # Yellow
              [(onepointhigh+1.)/2., 'rgb(244,109,67)'],
              [1.0, 'rgb(165,0,38)']], # Red

print(colorscale)
dfmean['text'] = dfmean['code']

data = [dict(
    type='choropleth',
    colorscale=colorscale,
    autocolorscale=False,
    locations=dfmean['code'],
    z=plot_z,
    locationmode='USA-states',
    text=dfmean['text'],
    marker=dict(
        line=dict(
            color='rgb(255,255,255)',
            width=2
        )),
    colorbar=dict(
        title=var)
)]

print(data)

layout = dict(
    title=title,
    geo=dict(
        scope='usa',
        projection=dict(type='albers usa'),
        showlakes=True,
        lakecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)'),
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig, filename='d3-cloropleth-map')
```

They key here is that on one run of this function,

`colorscale = ([[0.0, 'rgb(49,54,149)'], [0.0400, 'rgb(116,173,209)'], [0.0801, 'rgb(224,243,248)'], [0.0979, 'rgb(254,224,144)'], [0.5489, 'rgb(244,109,67)'], [1.0, 'rgb(165,0,38)']],)`

nevertheless, the resultant figure looks like the following:
[Choropleth plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZPtQ.png)

Basically, the colorscale is defaulting to the standard 'RdBu" colorscale. This is odd because the Plotly HTML being passed through the call tree contains my custom colorscale unchanged - it's as if it's disregarded on render.

Specifically plotly_html in plotly/offline.py contains:
`<div id="54d14a55-4470-4e77-908a-ed1aad3efd68" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" class="plotly-graph-div"></div><script type="text/javascript">window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};window.PLOTLYENV.BASE_URL="https://plot.ly";Plotly.newPlot("54d14a55-4470-4e77-908a-ed1aad3efd68", [{"type": "choropleth", "autocolorscale": false, "text": ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"], "colorbar": {"title": "Drugs/ Alcohol\u2217_norm"}, "locationmode": "USA-states", "z": [0.9574031223360088, 4.663833598074362, 0.7470654042509098, 0.45790667712096444, 0.7139322298296459, 1.215065339824984, 0.9474219012849346, 0.7353880993782959, 2.810812736720189, 0.6462863936749693, 0.9986899212581901, 6.548052464708055, 1.0090737091057922, 0.49457016318780755, 0.695353446901323, 0.9419458477900825, 0.8293205959460278, 0.7351136201837116, 1.6921332609878887, 1.9066962190394505, 0.8032201503740584, 1.572393730339865, 1.0845158832537063, 0.9784209575362792, 0.9652909590698142, 0.6196209448011111, 1.4865809187853425, 0.6422023875155145, 1.0212118831303278, 1.7328143913690517, 0.7946163933668561, 0.716044064254416, 1.0120916518088283, 0.9151593810825868, 2.046814218440964, 1.1652449211545537, 0.8550939805838285, 1.497308945837465, 0.6778640418859166, 0.9013539653339065, 1.6812599294250667, 1.1817300995782374, 1.0516933417009253, 0.720853315460788, 1.1375338872234784, 1.5900074550270746, 1.1047246521920622, 1.1058951057861155, 1.0357326707814427, 1.208933943847189, 1.3533084199230396], "colorscale": [[[0.0, "rgb(49,54,149)"], [0.04005519798766846, "rgb(116,173,209)"], [0.08011039597533692, "rgb(224,243,248)"], [0.09791270619207847, "rgb(254,224,144)"], [0.5489563530960392, "rgb(244,109,67)"], [1.0, "rgb(165,0,38)"]]], "locations": ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"], "marker": {"line": {"width": 2, "color": "rgb(255,255,255)"}}}], {"title": "D/A Compliance, normalized 2017", "geo": {"showlakes": true, "scope": "usa", "lakecolor": "rgb(255, 255, 255)", "projection": {"type": "albers usa"}}}, {"linkText": "Export to plot.ly", "showLink": true})</script>`

Which as you can see, has the right colorscale defined.

Is this is an obvious problem with my code? Or is there something in the renderer that is bypassing my custom colorscale - e.g. expected behaviour?

Thank you for any help!